# Port stops working after each use while using node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Here is my app.js file

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var io = require('socket.io'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    jquery = require('jquery'),
    routes = require('./routes');


/**
* Create app
*/

var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)  
  , io = io.listen(server);

/**
* Configure app
*/ 
app.configure(function(){ 
    app.set('port', 2121);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

});

// set both servers listening
server.listen( app.get('port') );


/**
* App gets
*/

app.get('/', routes.index );


console.log("listining on port " + app.get('port'));

io.set('log level', 1); // this gets rid of all the internal socket messages

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('made connection');


});
```

and in my index.js file which loads when index is rendered I have

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:2121');

});
```

The problem I am having is that this code will execute once, with the terminal displaying

```
My-MacBook-Pro-3:board_demo home$ node app.js 
   info  - socket.io started
listining on port 2121
made connection
```

However if I quit the process `^z` and try to run the code again `node app.js` I get

```
My-MacBook-Pro-3:one_board_demo home$ node app.js 
   info  - socket.io started
listining on port 2121
   warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

I then switch the port and the process repeats.

What could be causing this? I took most of the code I'm using now from a project I made before which did not have this problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's not clear to me: you run `node app.js` once, and it stops running by itself? Or are you trying to start it twice?

Comment: trying to start it twice

Comment: You can't have two separate processes listening on the same port (2121, in your case). That's what `EADDRINUSE` means ('address in use`). Also, ^Z doesn't quit a process, it will temporarily suspend it. But it will keep any ports occupied.

Comment: to me it seems that I'm only making it listen once, where do I tell a second process to listen and why would that make it work the first time and not any other? Also what should I be using instead of `^z`?

Comment: If you start your `app.js` twice, you have two processes that want to listen on the same port. If you want to quit a process, try ^C instead.